# what's the difference between pandas DataFrame methods agg() and apply()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are a number of SO questions regarding `agg` and `apply` on pandas `DataFrame.groupby()` objects, but I don't understand the difference between `DataFrame.agg()` and `DataFrame.apply()`. From the docs and the snippet below, they look the same to me. If there are issues specifically related to row operations that don't apply to operations on columns, I'd like to know about them.

```py
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([True, False, False])
b = pd.Series([False, False, False])
c = pd.Series([True, True, False])
d = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])

print(pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d}).agg(lambda x: print(len(x)), axis=1))
print()
print(pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d}).apply(lambda x: print(len(x)), axis=1))
```

```
4
4
4
0    None
1    None
2    None
dtype: object

4
4
4
0    None
1    None
2    None
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

They both actually call the same `frame_apply(...)` function with generally the same things going into them. One difference is that `df.agg()` (which actually itself is identical to `df.aggregate()`) has a step where it calls a `reconstruct_func()` function that does a little bit of cleanup/handling of what func you pass in.

For example, you can do `df['col1'].agg(sum)` and get a result, but if you do `df['col1'].apply(sum)` you'll get an error. Both `.agg()` and `.apply()` will work with the string `'sum'`, though - so we see that `.agg()` can take a little more variety. (This is all with a column of integers)

Comment: but df['col1'] is a series not a dataframe, right?

Comment: oh, good catch... and now that I look at that, I can call `df.agg(sum)` or `df.apply(sum)` both without any problems. That is, apply on the df seems a little more robust than on the series itself, and makes my point there pretty moot... I mean, `.agg()` does call a `reconstruct_func()`, but doesn't seem to have the effect I said it did...

I just spent some more time looking through the code and my conclusion is - not clear to me...